# Chef Powershell Run from File

Tags: windows, chef-infra

Using chef's powershell_script provider how would I reference a file stored on the chef server instead of having the code defined in the same file? Basically how can I call on a .ps1 located on the server from a chef client?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call unsigned powershell scripts directly within [`powershell_script`](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/resources.html#powershell-script), as long as [your execution policy allows it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee176949.aspx), which Chef does by default.

```
powershell_script "run some script" do
  code "c:/something/script.ps1"
end
```

If you want chef to deploy the script too, you can do it from the `/files` section of the cookbook with [`cookbook_file`](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_files.html).

Comment: Ah, okay. I was a bit confused by all the examples only using 'code' for actual code but I guess since it is just running a powershell command a script name does work true. But using this I would _have_ to put the script on the machine first and manually clean it up later. Not to much of a hassle, but it would have been nice to be able to run a remote script and have chef handle the temporary creation for me.

Comment: Well the DSL is just Ruby code after all. You could pull in the string for `code` into the client from anywhere. You could `File.read("script.ps1")` from the local cookbook cache. Even `Net::HTTP.get('example.com', 'script.ps1')`

Comment: I don't have much familiarity with ruby, but that seems to do basically exactly what I want! Thanks!

Comment: hmm. How would you pass powershell parameters using that 'code' property?

Comment: @JohnZaj I'm not sure you can. It looks like the `command` property takes a `String, Array` as parameters. I'm not sure why I suggested `code` over `command` for a local file.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple lines of code ,  dont forget to add \n at the end of each line in powershell_script resource's  code parameter.